# How to change the color of dot-icon showing the availability of agent in UserCard of Teams view in Twilio Flex Plugin?

Tags: reactjs, twilio, twilio-flex

I am new to Twilio Flex and want to customize the color of the dot showing the agent's availability if he is online or offline.
Here, is the image of the card showing the dot which I want to customize:
[User Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNwqq.png)
I tried taking some references from the below links:

1. https://assets.flex.twilio.com/docs/releases/flex-ui/2.0.0-beta.1/programmable-components/components/Supervisor%E2%80%A4TaskCard
2. https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/v1/components#usercard

Thank you in advance!